# Global Externs. Difference between string and char*

Tags: c++, string, global-variables, constants, extern

I have two questions:

1. I used to have a Constants.h containing

   ```
   const std::string PATH("/ram/")
   ```

   and it worked fine.

   But when I added

   ```
   const char* BLAH = "blah";
   ```

   to the same file. I got a redefinition error during linking.

   I get that it's because each compilation unit creates its own constants so this causes problem during linking, but why did it work for regular std::strings before and not for char*s?
2. So after that first issue, I decided to make everything extern and I now have a Constants.h and a Constants.cpp. But then I ran into another problem. I have another file Test.cpp, where a constant is defined as

   ```
   const std::string FOO(PATH + "booyah");
   ```

   This used to create "/ram/booyah" but now it's just "booyah". `PATH` has somehow become empty. I'm guessing it has something to do with the extern, and with constants being created during compile time. The constant `PATH` works okay during runtime.

Is this correct understanding? Is there a way to make all these work together nicely?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The relative timing of setting up `PATH` and `FOO` is implementation-defined. It looks like in your case `FOO` is created before `PATH`.

Comment: `PATH` is `const`. `BLAH` isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When something is a `const` it is automatically made `static` as in internal linkage.

Therefore when you had `const std::string` it was actually `static const std::string`.

This means every compilation unit gets its own copy of the string, which is wasteful of memory, although usually not a big concern.

To fix that, make `extern const std::string s;` in the header file and `extern const std::string s = "..";` in the source file.

To avoid requiring a source file, you can try this alternative, although it is potentially longer to compile. It will also allocate the string only once.

```
inline const std::string& GetStr()
{
    static const std::string s = "..";
    return s;
}
```

Now, why didn't `const char* BLAH` compile in the header? This is because BLAH is NOT a constant. Although it is a read-only pointer, the pointer is not constant, and can be changed to point to something else.

To make the code compile like it did with `const std::string`, you must use `const char *const BLAH = "..";`. Now it is a real constant and will compile as a `static`. This also suffers from the same problem that every compilation unit receives a copy of the pointer. It may also receive a copy of the string literal, depending on compiler optimizations. You can fix this by using the `extern` method above.

The order in which constants are initialized in the same compilation unit is the order in which they appear. However, the order in which constants are initialized between compilation units is NOT defined. This means an `extern` from one source file shouldn't depend on an `extern` from another source file.

You can fix this by defining all your constants in the same source file in the correct order, or using functions (possibly `inline`) to return the strings.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about internal and external linkages and their relationship with static and const. This cleared it up nicely!

Answer (score 1):

A global variable that is `const` has internal linkage. Your `BLAH` variable is not `const`, and so it defaults to external linkage. You could either declare it `static`, or simply make it `const`:

```
const char * const BLAH = "blah";
```

If you find it difficult to spell type names in C++, you can use type aliases to make your life easier:

```
using ccp = const char *;

const std::string foo = "foo";
const ccp bar = "bar";
```

Comment: Cool.  I didn't know about this "using" syntax apperently is C++11.

Comment: @YasserAsmi: Alternative C-like syntax: `typedef const char * ccp;`

Answer (score 0):

Since the header file can be included ffrom multiple CPP files, you would get conflicts.  You can use the static keyword.

I typically do:
      static const char* const str= "blah";